# Assign a string in a column if the corresponding row of another column contains a certain substring, else another string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
index | Creative Size       | Business Model
1     | Something trueview  |
2     | truviewhello        |
3     | dunno               |
4     | str                 |
5     | str                 |
```

I want to write a code that if there is 'trueview' in a column assing the label 'CPV' to the corresponding row in Business Model, else it assigns 'CPM'.
Expected output is:

```
index | Creative Size       | Business Model
1     | Something trueview  | CPV
2     | truviewhello        | CPV
3     | dunno               | CPM
4     | str                 | CPM
5     | str                 | CPM
```

I come up with this:

```
count=0
for i in db_all['Creative Size']:
    if 'trueview' in i:
        db_all.loc[count, 'Business Model']='CPV'
        
    else:
        db_all.loc[count, 'Business Model']='CPM'
                
    count = count+1
```

It works but it's slow, any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
db_all['Business Model'] = np.where(db_all['Creative Size'].str.contains('trueview'), 
                                    'CPV', 
                                    'CPM')
```